# How to upload image ,save in db and retrieve from db using ember.js and MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and i'm trying to do something I need to upload image in my webapp and need to save the image in the db and retrieve it from db how can I do that

Comment: What's this got to do with PostgreSQL? You seem to be asking about a JavaScript framework - and presumably some kind of back-end server. **What have you already tried**? What have you read or looked at already? Have you tried to split this up into several smaller and simpler tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking for ***Tutorial***, anyway's please have a look at below link's *(in case you have missed it)*

[Displaying Image Gallery using Ember.js](http://www.infoq.com/articles/emberjs) and [A-sample-real-time-web-application-using-Ember-js](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511031/A-sample-real-time-web-application-using-Ember-js).

The prior will develop a simple photo viewer/carousel Ember.js application that is able to display a horizontal list of images.

The later is a good article using MVC4 API's and Ember from [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511031/A-sample-real-time-web-application-using-Ember-js).